# no such element Exception when trying to driver.findElement(By

Tags: selenium, remotewebdriver

My code looks like that (in java), running on chrome:

```
@Test
     public void verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed() throws Exception {              
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(this.RED_ALERTS_BTN));
}
```

I declared RED_ALERTS_BTN:

```
public final String RED_ALERTS_BTN = "#divAOISummary > div > div.list-summary.list-summary-red.active";
```

I also tried to go by simply using id :

```
@Test
     public void verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed() throws Exception {              
         driver.findElement(By.id(this.RED_ALERTS_BTN));
}

public final String RED_ALERTS_BTN = "divAOISummary";
```

seems like tried everything (even with xpath) and I still get the 'no such element' ;

the actual HTML :

```
<div id="pnlRightDB-targetEl" style="position: absolute; width: 320px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 1px;"><div class="x-panel x-box-item x-panel-default" id="pnlAOIHeader" style="left: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 320px; top: 0px; height: 215px;"><div id="pnlAOIHeader-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default" style="width: 320px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 215px;"><div id="pnlAOIHeader-clearEl" class="x-clear" role="presentation"></div><div id="pnlAOIHeader_Content" class="">  
                                <div id="divAOIHeader" class="clearfix" style="height: 213px;">
        <div class="panel-title">Incidents<span class="icon-refresh" title="Refresh the Incident List" onclick="refreshIncidentList()"></span></div>
        <div id="divAOISummary" class="IncidentSummary"><div class="list-summary-holder">
                <div class="list-summary list-summary-red active" title="1 Red Alert">1</div>
                <div class="list-summary list-summary-yellow" title="No Yellow Alerts">0</div>
                <div class="list-summary list-summary-green" title="No Green Alerts">0</div>
        </div>      
</div>
```

anybody can help or give me an idea ? Seems like all other test cases run just fine using similar technic;
many thanks for any suggestion !
aluchia

Answer (score 1):

I would try with `explicit` wait and wait for the element until it's located.

```
@Test
public void verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed() throws Exception {              
         By byCss = By.cssSelector("byCss");

         WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byCss));

}
```

Comment: thank you, but I can't see my button in your code, ho will it find it ?

Comment: @Aluchia change `By byCss = By.cssSelector("byCss");` and replace byCss with the cssSelector you want

Comment: I used this line in my @Test   WebElement myredbutton = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(this.RED_ALERTS_BTN)));

Comment: FAILED: verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException.addInfo(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
 at test.DashboardTests.verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed(DashboardTests.java:58)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: I do not see any button on the `html` you have provide. Can you double check and tell me what if that's correct?

Comment: well, they specified as class, but actually clickable :

Comment: <div class="list-summary list-summary-red active" title="1 Red Alert">1</div>
                <div class="list-summary list-summary-yellow" title="No Yellow Alerts">0</div>
                <div class="list-summary list-summary-green" title="No Green Alerts">0</div>

Comment: So you want to click on  the one with text `1`?

Comment: yes, the one has 'Red Alert' and '1' ;  When I click on it I get a list of alerts and layers displayed. That;s why I used css, as there is no id.  is that wrong way to implement ?  thank you for trying to help.

Comment: but even if I don't click on it, my driver still cannot find that element

Comment: Try `@Test
public void verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed() throws Exception {              
         By byCss = By.cssSelector("[title='1 Red Alert']");

         WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byCss));

}`

Comment: thanks !!!  I  tried ur code, then realized the alerts picking the number on it dinamically from DB, so always different, can't be hardcoded, so I had to modify your line like this :  By byCss = By.cssSelector("[title~='Red Alert']");

Comment: and got it failed again:  FAILED: verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException.addInfo(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
 at test.DashboardTests.verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed(DashboardTests.java:67)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorI

Comment: It's hard to troubleshot without knowing about the whole page. Try this `@Test
public void verifyRedAlertCountDisplayed() throws Exception {              
         By byXpath = By.xpath("//div[.='1']");

         WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath));

}`

Comment: Unfortunately it failed with the same trace

Comment: it seems like the driver can't see anything on this page, do you think there is something special about the page or something wrong with the driver?  I I have another page with .aspx and all works on that page.

Comment: Make sure if that page has any iframe and, if the element inside that

Comment: there are no iframes or frames on the page, how do I attach .txt file for you to look at the full page html ?

Comment: in my @Test  : dtw = new DashboardTab();
  dtw.verifyObjectsOnRightPanel();

Comment: public void verifyObjectsOnRightPanel () throws Exception{         driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(this.DEFAUL_VIEW_URL); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen1018"));}    so once on second line where it needs to findElement -  it  chokes.  finds no elements.  But gives me the currentUrl;  so seems to be ok with driver.  something else.